# Unless TV/HDMI switch set to RPie, resolution is too big

Tags: hdmi, retropie

So, I have a RetroPie running on Pi-3B, with the RemotePie HAT controlling on/off.

When I turn it on, unless my TV (1080p HD) and HDMI switch are set to the inputs to display the Pie, the display is stretched and displays too big (I can't see the bottom options in Emulationstation.)

Is there any way to force the resolution to whatever it is when the display is correct?

I use a Harmony remote to turn everything on and set input, and my HDMI switch doesn't allow me to change to an input that currently doesn't have signal.

Answer (score 1):

The settings is done in `config.txt`, the documentation for all options is found here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/

Comment: Is there a way to see what options it's using now and hardcode them into the config.txt? I see dozens of combinations I could use as a trial/error method, but that would take so long.

Comment: I'm not sure about RetroPi. It could be "fbset -s".

Comment: Sorry this is a bit old, but was wondering if this would mean anything. I don't understand all the options...
Would it be Group 1, option 34 then, which is 1080p 30Hz?

pi@retropie:~ $ fbset -s

mode "1824x984"
    geometry 1824 984 1824 984 32
    timings 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    rgba 8/16,8/8,8/0,8/24
endmode